# mysql #1064 error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть на сайте форма, работает у всех пользователей четко. Но тут у одного пользователя стала выдавать ошибку:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near `` 'FROM `price` WHERE id_item='11051'' at line 1. ``

Никак не могу понять, если запрос некорректен, он бы ведь тогда у всех не работал? А сбой идет только у одного пользователя...
в скрипте выглядит это так:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT naimenovanie, {$price} 
                      FROM `price` 
                      WHERE `id_item`='$id_item'") 
             or die (mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $izdelie=$row['naimenovanie'];
    $cena=$row[$price];
}
```

Comment: А полный запрос как выглядит? и почему id как строка, а не как число? И почему пользователь может видеть ошибки от БД?

Comment: И как этот запрос формируется, тоже очень интересно...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это любители `or die(mysql_error())` (или как там оно) видимо

Comment: Вопрос можно редактировать, если что. Добавьте туда еще как и откуда получается этот `$id_item`

Comment: что передается в `$price`?, если там будет строка вида `10 000` (с пробелом) то запрос очевидно, работать не будет.

Comment: У вас `$price` отклеился

Comment: @teran, тогда бы часть была в сообщении об ошибке(или вообще за алиас бы сошёл). Он у него пустой

Comment: @vp_arth я с mysql давненько не работал, но что-то мне помнится, что не всегда он показывает прямо часть где непосредственно ошибка.

Comment: @teran в $price передается имя соответствующего столбца таблицы `price`.  Дело в том, что у всех, кроме одного все работает прекрасно.

Comment: ну дак, какое наименование столбца передается у этого пользователя? и, главное, откуда это наименование берется?

Comment: @teran в зависимости от select в форме, конкретно у этого пользователя будет `$price='price1'`

Comment: @hidden у вас есть возможность выполнить данный запрос напрямую в SQL? например через phpmyadmin и возможно вам покажет более детальную ошибку

Comment: @programmer403 в phpmyadmin запрос выполняется корректно, выдает то, что ожидается, как и у 99% пользователей)

Comment: @hidden все равно дело значит в $price т.к. если переменная пустая получается "SELECT naimenovanie, FROM...". Вы что-то говорили про select в форме данные с формы передаются через JS?

Comment: @programmer403 без JS, только php. Прикол в том, что с другого компа перезаполнили форму точь-в-точь, как пользователь - все работает.

Comment: @hidden значит баг не воспроизводится, можно закрывать тикет))) а ошибки БД лучше убрать от юзера.

Answer (score 0):

'FROM `price` WHERE id_item='11051'' at line 1.

Синтаксическая же ошибка, присмотритесь к значению id_item  ->   id_item='11051''

Answer (score 0):

Переменная $price - пустая строка. MySQL не понимает, откуда FROM после запятой.